# how to do dynamic sized json response parsing?

Tags: json, http-post

I have a `http` get call which will populate the entire student list with id, name and class. Can anyone help me on how to find the id of the kid for a name?
The response will be in the below mentioned format.

```html
 [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "SchoolName": "Cp", 
        "StudentList": [
            {
                "id": 1, 
                "name": "jerin", 
                "class": 1, 
            }, 
            {
                "id": 2, 
                "name": "john",
                "class": 2, 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This will be as big as the number of students. If i need to find the id of  Jerin, how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved easily.
This is a json array. so we can use jsonArray and we can parse through it.